# How can I make a <details> element keyboard accessible?

Tags: html

I've recently discovered the [`<details>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element) element. Although [support is limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=details), it seems pretty interesting.

There's one major problem though: it isn't keyboard accessible. In other words, it's impossible to <kbd>TAB</kbd> into the element. It doesn't seem to receive focus, so it requires a mouse click to reveal the `<summary>`.

- Is there any way to make this keyboard accessible?
- Is this perhaps just webkit's faulty implementation or is this the way it is designed?

Demo (webkit only): http://jsfiddle.net/rkq3M/

Comment: Focus is easy enough to add. Just stick tabindex=0 attribute on the element. Sadly, this doesn't really help as there's still no way without JS to open or close the element. I'm afraid this is par for course for Webkit, where accessibility always seems to be an afterthought. For all the criticism of IE, Microsoft have always taken accessibility seriously.

Comment: I see, thanks Alochi. Sounds like filing the bug report was the correct course of action. Too bad `tabindex` doesn't help. I have to admit though, the behavior of this element seems a bit like too good to be true, or quite unlike any other element; almost like `<marquee>` but semantic. Like someone stayed up too late coming up with the idea.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. [My own view on the element can be found here](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/#comment-17101)

Comment: That's pretty much how I feel. It seems like some kind of a "webapp" element with this predefined behavior for *convenience's* sake, adding nothing semantically ("semantic" should be in sarcastic quotes in my above comment) and just cluttering up the namespace and being confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of issue, I would recommend raising a bug on the WebKit project page:

https://bugs.webkit.org/

Bear in mind that the details element is new and has yet to be refined, so it is worth getting it fixed in WebKit, rather than trying to polyfill a fix just for your specific implementation.

Comment: That's more-or-less what I figured: too early to tell for sure how this element should behave, but I also thought there might be some way of handling focus that I was overlooking and that hack/polyfill wouldn't actually be necessary. Well I took your advice and filed a bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75478

Comment: @Madmartigan good work raising the bug - issues like this are important.